# Python getting Itunes song

Tags: python, applescript, itunes

I have been doing a little bit of research and haven't found anything that is quite going to work. I want to have python know what the current song playing in iTunes is so I can serially send it to my Arduino.

I have seen Appscript but it is no longer supported and from what I have read full of a few bugs now that it hasn't been updated.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.2 & iTunes 10.0.1

Anyone got any ideas on how to make this work. Any information is greatly appreciated.

FYI: My project is a little 1.8' colour display screen that I am going to have serval pieces of information on RAM HDD CPU Song etc.

Comment: Cool project, wish u well.

Comment: Thanks it is going well so far but have to get my loops right in python and it will almost be finished

Comment: If you Scrobble your track plays to Last.fm you can then use their API to get what you're currently playing or have played recently etc. That is how I and others do things, we used PHP though, but the API should work with most any decent programming language. There are widgets too for Last.fm

Answer (score 4):

After 5 minutes of more searching I found that the ScriptingBridge will work

Information found here [LINK](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html)

```
#Information and basic source from
#http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html

#!/usr/bin/python
#imports for iTunes support
from Foundation import *
from ScriptingBridge import *

import time

import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A600afCt')

iTunes = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")

#print iTunes.currentTrack().name()
#print iTunes.currentTrack().artist()
#print iTunes.currentTrack().album()

outputString = iTunes.currentTrack().name() + "[" + iTunes.currentTrack().artist() + "[" + iTunes.currentTrack().album()
time.sleep(10)
print outputString
ser.write(outputString)
time.sleep(10)
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a simple Automator workflow to retrieve the current iTunes song. Try these two actions for starters:

- **iTunes: Get the Current Song**
- **Utilities: Run Shell Script**

Change the shell script to `cat > ~/itunes_track.txt` and you should have a text file containing the path of the current track. Once you get your data out of Automator you should be all set :)